# Replace values from a certain row onwards column-wise

Tags: matlab, matrix, multidimensional-array, replace, vectorization

I have a `10x5` double matrix `mat`. I also have a `1x5` row vector `start_rows`. In `mat` I would like to replace all numbers from specific rows onwards using `start_rows`. I could use a loop and replace all the numbers column by column. However, I'm sure there is some vectorized solution.

```
mat = nan(10, 5);
start_rows = [3,5,1,7,2];

% How to avoid that loop
for idx = 1 : numel(start_rows)
    mat(start_rows(idx):end, idx) = 1;
end
```

Comment: Is your original matrix always full of zeros? Are you always replacing with ones (or if not - is is some constant value)?

Comment: I will be replacing with a constant value, such as +1 or -1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be solved comparing an array of the following form to your `start_rows` vector:

```
     1     1     1     1     1
     2     2     2     2     2
     3     3     3     3     3
     4     4     4     4     4
     5     5     5     5     5
     6     6     6     6     6
     7     7     7     7     7
     8     8     8     8     8
     9     9     9     9     9
    10    10    10    10    10
```

which will return a logical array for when the condition is met (this uses broadcasting AKA implicit expansion).

---

If `mat` always contains zeros, and you're replacing with ones:

```
(1:size(mat,1)).'+ mat >= start_rows;
```

If `mat` is nonzero:

```
(1:size(mat,1)).'+ 0*mat >= start_rows;             % option 1
(1:size(mat,1)).'+ zeros(size(mat)) >= start_rows;  % option 2
```

If replacing with values other than `1` (or `true`):

```matlab
((1:size(mat,1)).'+ 0*mat >= start_rows) * newVal;
```

Comment: Just a small addition to prevent possible follow-up questions from people using older MATLAB versions: Implicit expansion is available since MATLAB R2016b.